# Does tmux use /etc/shells to pick the shell it's going to use?

Tags: shell, tmux

When I run `$SHELL` from `tmux` I get `/bin/sh`, and `/etc/shells` has this listed as the very first item in it's list.  So does `tmux` grab it from there that and use it as the shell?

When I run `tmux show -g` I get:

```
assume-paste-time 1
base-index 0
bell-action any
bell-on-alert off
default-command ""
default-shell "/bin/sh"
destroy-unattached off
detach-on-destroy on
display-panes-active-colour red
display-panes-colour blue
display-panes-time 1000
display-time 750
history-limit 2000
lock-after-time 0
lock-command "lock -np"
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse off
mouse-utf8 on
prefix C-b
prefix2 <NONE>
renumber-windows off
repeat-time 500
set-remain-on-exit off
set-titles off
set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T" #{session_alerts}"
status on
status-interval 15
status-justify left
status-keys emacs
status-left "[#S] "
status-left-length 10
status-left-style default
status-position bottom
status-right " "#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
status-right-length 40
status-right-style default
status-style fg=black,bg=green
status-utf8 on
update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
visual-activity off
visual-bell off
visual-silence off
word-separators " -_@"
```

`default-shell "/bin/sh"` seems to be of interest...but I will also note that I do not have an `/etc/tmux.conf` for defaults.

Comment: I think it inherits it from its parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. tmux fills in default-shell when the server is started by first looking at $SHELL, if that is not valid it tries the user's shell (from the passwd db) and if that doesn't work then /bin/sh.

/etc/shells just lists what shells a user is allowed to set as their shell (with chsh or whatnot), it doesn't specify what any user's actual shell is.

Answer (score 1):

> So does tmux grab it from there that and use it as the shell?

No. Choosing the shell that should be ran is described in `man tmux`:

> default-shell path
>
> Specify the default shell.  This is used as the login shell for new
>   windows when the default-command option is set to empty, and must be
>   the full path of the executable.  When started tmux tries to set a
>   default value from the first suitable of the SHELL environment
>   variable, the shell returned by getpwuid(3), or /bin/sh.  This option
>   should be configured when tmux is used as a login shell.

First, `tmux` starts `$SHELL`.  `$SHELL` is usually set at the very
early stage when you log in to your system, for example by your X
login manager.

Then, it parses `/etc/passwd` using `getpwuid()` that you can read
more about in `man getpwuid`.  Finally, if both method fail, it starts
`/bin/sh`.

As you see, `/etc/shells` is not used at all by `tmux` in order to
determine what shell to run. You can even temporarily rename it and
`tmux` would still work:

```
sudo mv /etc/shells /etc/shells.bak
```

`/etc/shells` specifies *Pathnames of valid login shells (optional)*
as described in
[FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf).  For
example, it's used by `chsh` to validate the name of the shell.